# Linker error on Including Frame Work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, linker, ios5

In my application, I am including a private framework.

Framework file I have in my project.

When I am Running the app I have got the linker error shown below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MessageWebLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MessageUIAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Actually this framework was working well in ios 3 but as soon as I change the base sdk 5.0,
It gives me an error.
MessageWebLayer is the name of the header file.

****EDIT1**********

When I am including the private framework on sample project it works fine with both iOS 3.2 and iOS 5.0.
But still I am getting an error on my existing project.

---

But, I have found one link if anybody has some clue.
[Nice answer but could not get it](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1171337)

*****EDIT2*********
In the list first answer state that Find the right Build for your project? but How? 
If I am watching it somewhere it is written that /Users/company/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyappUI-azodwyjwfonowicennduyclhdest/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyappUI.app/MyappUI normal i386

What is the meaning at last they have written i386?

does it have any connection with my build?

Answer (score 2):

The "symbol(s) not found for architecture i386" bit indicates that the lib has not got binaries compatible with the intel processors in your mac (as presumably you are trying to run on the simulator). They are most likely built for the ARMv6/ARMv7 processor architectures which are used for iOS devices. You need to find the right build for the i386 architecture and have conditional links based on which platform you are running on. Or just run it on the device.

Comment: But when I am including the same Framework on other  sample projects it runs well.But as I can see Linker is also giving me an error like Ld /Users/taxsmart2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MessageUI-azodwyjwfonowicennduyclhdest/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MessageUI.app/MessageUI normal i386 What does it means.

Comment: ulator/MessageUI.app/MessageUI normal i386  what is the meaning of i386 architecture they have return.

Comment: In your answer you have said find the right build , please elaborate this?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that this framework is no longer included or had its path or name changed. Since it's private, no one should be using it as it won't get approved in the AppStore. Private frameworks also don't have public documentation and must be avoided at all cost because Apple won't give any support to it and may change it as they like, which might have been the case here.

What are you trying to achieve? Isn't there a way around using private APIs?
Post some code and maybe we can help you more.